# Kafka Streams Binding: Cannot get state store because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I use the infrastructure of Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binding for stream processing.

Here is the main KafkaStream-methods:

```
private static final String READ_STORE_NAME = "readMessageStore";

  @Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, ContentModel>> filter() {
    return in -> in.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(ContentModel.class)))
            .reduce(this::mergeObjects, Materialized.as(READ_STORE_NAME));
}

private ContentModel mergeObjects(final ContentModel reducer, final ContentModel materialized) {      
    return reducer;
}
```

Configuration of binding:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filter-in-0:
     destination: topic
```

I deploy 2 instances of application, which separated by ApplicationId as follows:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.filter.applicationId = <Id>
```

But on the stage of deploy I receive:

> IllegalStateException: Error when retrieving state store: j readMessageStore
>
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store readMessageStore because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING

From that [Unable to open store for Kafka streams because invalid state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534195/unable-to-open-store-for-kafka-streams-because-invalid-state)  I found out, that I need (apparently) to wait for the second RUNNING state before query.

But how can I set this delay in the  Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binding environment, considering that all state transitions in this case realized "under the hood"?

Comment: Which broker are you using? From the other SO thread you linked, it looks like if you are using brokers >= 2.2.0, then this is already fixed? Did you try that?

Comment: In case of kafka streams binder, as I understand,  brokers is "under the hood".

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the health indicator and then write the listener to monitor it for REBALANCE before the second RUNNING.

refer this
[Health Indicator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_health_indicator)

Comment: I got it about health indicator. And could you provide with some more details about writing the listener to monitor? May be some useful refer ?